# How to force expr to address a value as a string and not a number?

Tags: tcl

When TCL gets a string that starts with a `0` as its return value, it'll treat it as an octal number and will return the decimal value of the octal number. Is there a way to circumvent it and force `expr` to address the value as a string?

I encounter this problem because I have a line:

```
set val [expr {( $obj == "" ) ? "" : [$obj data]}]
```

And one the results of the `[$obj data]` operation is a binary string starting with 0, and the `expr` turns it into another number. Is there a way to fix this without turning the `expr` into an `if`?

Answer (score 1):

The `expr` command is *defined* to convert its result to a number if it is legal to do so. It's been this way since… well, since at least Tcl ***7.0*** and probably since the first version of Tcl to have an `expr` command (which takes it a hugely long way back). This means that if you return a valid octal number (which `09` isn't), `expr` *will* convert it.

If this behaviour isn't desired, don't use `expr` for conditionals; use `if`. In your case, this works quite nicely (and I think it's clearer this time with the `then` and `else` pseudo-keywords).

```
set val [if {$obj == ""} then {} else {$obj data}]
```

(At the bytecode level, this generates almost the identical bytecode to what your original does, except it omits a call to the `tryCvtToNumeric` operation; that's the one you say you *don't* want!)

Comment: If the user specifically wants string comparison, I would suggest using `[string equal]`.

Answer (score 0):

[warning: not an answer but a coment requiring formatting]

I'm not observing the same results

```
% proc obj {args} {return "09"}  ;#specifically using invalid octal value
% set obj obj
obj
% $obj data
09
% set val [expr {($obj == "") ? "" : [$obj data]}]
09
% info patchlevel
8.6.1
```

What Tcl version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 8.4, the problem is that if you will try 0101 and not 09 then you'll have the problem.

Comment: yes, I see. same reault in 8.6. Even quoting `"[$obj data]"` didn't help. Use `if` instead of clever expr tricks, your code will be more clear.

Comment: It was a `tryCvtToNumeric` bytecode that was causing the problem…